# RegEx to find non-existence of white space prefix but not include the character in the match?

Tags: c#, regex

So i have the following RegEx for the purpose of finding and adding whitespace:

```
(\S)(\()
```

So for a string like "SomeText(Somemoretext)" I want to update this to "SomeText (Somemoretext)" it matches "t(" and so my replace eliminates the "t" from the string which is not good. I also do not know what the character could be, I'm merely trying to find the non-existence of whitespace.

Is there a better expression to use or is there a way to exclude the found character from the match returned so that I can safely replace without catching characters i do not want to replace?

Thanks

Comment: You have to replace with `$1 $2` or use lookarounds `(?<=\S)(?=\()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a space between a dot and a character using simple search/replace with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124716/inserting-a-space-between-a-dot-and-a-character-using-simple-search-replace-with)

Comment: I have tried a back reference (?<=\.)(\() and this is not doing it for me

Comment: @revo I tried yours and this is the closest i have come, however it seems to be excluding the ( also so my overwrite is causing a (( to be written

Comment: `str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\S)(\()", "$1 $2");`

Comment: @Nugs `(?<=[\S-[\(]])(?=\()` will help if you have string like `SomeText((Somemoretext))`: `regex.Replace(input, " ");`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect the absence of space before a specific character (such as bracket) after a word, how about the following?

```
\b(?=[^\s])\(
```

This will detect `words` ( [a-zA-z0-9_] that are followed by a bracket, without a space).

(if I got your problem correctly) you can replace the `full match` with `(` and  get exactly what you need.

In case you need to look for absence spaces before a symbol (like a bracket) in any kind of text (as in the text may be `non-word`, such as punctuation) you might want to use the following instead.

```
^(?:\S*)(\()(?:\S*)$
```

When using this, your result will be in `group 1`, instead of just `full match` (which now contains the whole line, if a line is matched).

Answer (score 0):

I find lookarounds hard to read and would prefer using [substitutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) in the replacement string instead:

```
var s = Regex.Replace("test1() test2()", @"(\S)\(", "$1 (");
Debug.Assert(s == "test1 () test2 ()");
```

`$1` inserts the first capture group from the regex into the replacement string which is the non-space character before the opening parenthesis `(`.